# Printing in C# WPF - PrintDialog.PrintVisual method works on one computer and doesn't work on other

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, printdialog

I have a problem, that i'm trying to solve for about a week now and I decided to sign up and ask you, because everything I have tried has failed.

I have WPF application written in C#. My biggest concern is printing. I have following piece of code:

```
TransformedBitmap tb = new TransformedBitmap();
RotateTransform transform = new RotateTransform(90);

tb.BeginInit();
tb.Source = myBitmapImage;
tb.Transform = transform;
tb.EndInit();

PrintDialog myPrintDialog = new PrintDialog();

var dv = new DrawingVisual();
using (var dc = dv.RenderOpen())
{   
     dc.DrawImage(tb, new Rect(0, 0, myPrintDialog.PrintableAreaWidth, myPrintDialog.PrintableAreaHeight));
}

myPrintDialog.PrintVisual(dv, "Image");
```

I have tried this code on few computers, with different Windows versions. Works fine on Win 10, Win 8.1, Win 7, even on my old Win XP.

But lately I have tried to run this application on ASUS X553M with Win 8.1. Application hangs after code given above. And of course, nothing is printed.

I took closer look to the code,  I've debugged this code and I figure out that it stops in line:

```
myPrintDialog.PrintVisual(dv, "Image");
```

File is sent to printer, but nothing more happens. Interesting thing is, that in printer's queue file has status: "buffering" all the time and doesn't change. I've tried with few printers, both physical and virtual printers - same thing, never ending buffering... 
Another strange thing, I have tested printers and they seems to be working correctly. Printing test page from printer's driver has succeeded.

It is strange thing for me, because - as I said - code works fine on other computers.
In last few days I have searched answer in the Internet, I have cleaned and reset print spooler service in Windows system. I have installed every possible update on that Asus X553M Win 8, I have even updated it to Windows 10. I've created a new account, for new admin user, because I thought maybe user profile is corrupt. And nothing changed, still doesn't printing... and application still hangs on that line.

I would appreciate every clue, what can be wrong or where should I look... I'm counting on your suggestions. I have to make this laptop (or my app) work properly. Changing laptop is not an option, so you are my last hope.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does printing work from other apps?

Comment: Thank you for your interest. Yes, I have tested printing from Windows Picture Browser and buffering takes less than a second, then picture is printing.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar problem where I was able to print from some computers but not from one, on a physical printer (working OK with XPS). I finally got a working solution here:

» https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9eb79e11-ee5a-4687-ad4c-a6d96276a8f4/printing-a-wpf-usercontrol?forum=wpf

```
        UserControlToPrint.Measure(New Size(816, 1056))
        UserControlToPrint.Arrange(New Rect(New Size(816, 1056)))
        UserControlToPrint.UpdateLayout()
```